# Computing expected value of exponential

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Let $U$ and $V$ be two independent random variables where $E[U]=$ and $E[U^2]=1$ and where $V$ is standard Gaussian.

We also let $W=U+V$. How to compute the following expectation or find an an upper bound
\begin{align}
E\left[ e^{{(W-U)^2-(W-aU)^2}}\right]
\end{align}
where $a>0$. 
Observer, that the above can be re-written like
\begin{align}
E\left[ e^{{(W-U)^2-(W-aU)^2}}\right]&=E\left[ e^{{V^2-(1-a)^2U^2-2(1-a)UV-V^2}}\right]\\
&=E\left[ e^{{-(1-a)^2U^2-2(1-a)UV}}\right]
\end{align}

The question is what to do next? 
For example, since we want to upper bound Jensen's inequality does not apply.

I was thinking Cauchy Schwarz

\begin{align}
E\left[ e^{{-(1-a)^2U^2-2(1-a)UV}}\right] \le \sqrt{E\left[ e^{{-2(1-a)^2U^2}}\right] E \left[ e^{e^{{-4(1-a)UV}}} \right]}
\end{align}

But what to do next? Also, is there a way of not using  Cauchy Schwarz?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MGF for the standard normal random variable, 
$$ \eqalign{E\left[ \exp(-(1-a)^2 U^2 - 2(1-a)UV)\right] &= E \left[ \exp(-(1-a)^2 U^2)\; E\left[\exp(- 2(1-a)UV)|U\right]\right]\cr
&= E\left[ \exp((1-a)^2 U^2)\right]}  $$

Unfortunately, you didn't give us enough information about $U$ to say much about this.  It could be infinite.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying to keep $U$ as general as possible. With a finite variance assumption can we at least have an upper bound?

Comment: Also, could you please explain to me more why the term $E[exp(-2(1-a) UV|V]]=1$?

Comment: Sorry, that should be $|U$, not $|V$.    And it's not $1$, it''s $\exp(2(1-a)^2U^2)$.  The moment generating function for the standard normal random variable is $E[\exp(tV)] = \exp(t^2/2)$.

Comment: As I said, it could be infinite, so there's no upper bound.