# Computing expectation of: $\small E\left[f(Z,U)e^{\frac{V^2-(V+W)^2}{2}} \right] $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have three mutually independent random variables  $U,V,W$ where
$W \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, $V \sim \mathcal{N}(0,c)$ and $E[U]=0$, $E[U^2]=1$.

Lets define $Z=U+V+W$.

Can we compute (or simplify) the following  quantity
\begin{align}
E\left[f(Z,U)e^{\frac{V^2-(V+W)^2}{2}} \right]
\end{align}
where $f$ is some deterministic function. For now I don't want to make any assumptions about $f$ but if we need to here are some assumptions that we can make:

1. $f(Z,U)>0$
2. $0 \le E\left[f(Z,U)\right] \le 1$

I was thinking some thing like this

\begin{align}
E\left[f(Z,U)e^{\frac{V^2-(V+W)^2}{2}} \right]&=
E\left[ E\left[f(Z,U)e^{\frac{V^2-(V+W)^2}{2}} \Big| Z,U\right] \right]\\
&=E\left[ f(Z,U)E\left[e^{\frac{V^2-(V+W)^2}{2}} \Big| Z,U\right] \right]
\end{align}

Now the question is how to compute the quantity $E\left[e^{\frac{V^2-(V+W)^2}{2}} \Big| Z,U\right]$. The good think is that $V$ and $W$ is are Gaussian.

Note that we can rewrite $E\left[e^{\frac{V^2-(V+W)^2}{2}} \Big| Z,U\right]=E\left[e^{\frac{-W^2-2VW}{2}} \Big| Z,U\right]$.
The above looks like a moment generating function (but conditioned) and is related to this [question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395957/computing-expected-value-of-exponential/1395993#1395993)

Thank you in advance  for any help.

Comment: Conditioning by $(Z,U)$ is to condition by $(U,V+W)$ hence your conditional expectation is $$e^{-(V+W)^2/2}E(e^{V^2/2}\mid U,V+W)$$ Furthermore, $$E(e^{V^2/2}\mid U,V+W)=E(e^{V^2/2}\mid V+W).$$ The latter involves the joint distribution of $(V,V+W)$. Can you compute it?

Comment: Thanks. Since, $V$ and $W$ are independent and also Gaussian, maybe  I can. I will give it a try. I think it can be done, right?