# Bound on $E\left[f(Z,U)\exp \left(\frac{tZ^2}{2}\right) \right]$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, expectation, moment-generating-functions

Suppose $Z$ is standard normal and $U$ is another random variable. Let  $f(Z,U) \ge 0$ also  $ E[f^p(Z,U)] <\infty$ for $1 \le p <\infty$> we want to find a bound on the following expectation 
\begin{align}
E\left[f(Z,U)\exp \left(\frac{tZ^2}{2}\right) \right]
\end{align}
for $ t \in (0,1)$.

The assumption is that 
\begin{align}
E\left[f(Z,U)\exp \left(\frac{tZ^2}{2}\right) \right] < \infty 
\end{align}
fo all $t \in (0,1)$

The bound I have is due to Holder
\begin{align}
E\left[f(Z,U)e^{\frac{tZ^2}{2}} \right]  &\le  \left(E\left[f(Z,U)^q \right] \right)^{1/q} \left(E\left[\exp \left(\frac{tpZ^2}{2}\right) \right] \right)^{1/p}\\
&=  \left(E\left[f(Z,U)^q \right] \right)^{1/q} \left(\frac{1}{1-tp} \right)^{\frac{1}{2p}} 
\end{align}
the last  using by  moment generation function of  $Z^2$ which is valid for $tp < 1$.

However, **my problem** is that the above bound is only finite for $tp < 1$ or in other words for $t < \frac{1}{p} \le 1$ and does not hold for all values of $t \in (0,1)$.

My question is this the best bound we can do? Or is there a better bound?

This question is related to something I asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397294/computing-expectation-of-small-e-leftfz-ue-fracv2-vw22-right?rq=1)  but not exactly

Thank you

Comment: Did you complete the solution of the other question?

Comment: To get a bound valid for every $t>1$, apply what you did to some $p$ in $(1,1/t)$, for example, $$p=\frac{t+1}{2t}.$$

Comment: @Did  Yes, after your hint. I was able to solve it.

Comment: But you posted nothing on the site?

Comment: @Did should I answer it? I will then. Thanks for help with this one.

Comment: @Did I want to ask you another question. Is Holder inequality the only way approach the problem of bounding product of random variables?